# autocomplete search with jquery-ui - doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5

When I fill search box, auto-completion doesn't work correctly. My query doesn't work.

Below is my html code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#keyword').autocomplete({
       source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
         url : '/search',
         dataType: "json",
    data: {
       username: request.term
        },
     success: function( data ) {
      response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
      return {
            id: '<B>' + item.id + '</B>',
       value: item.value
      }
     }));
    }
        });
       },
       autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 2,
         select: function(event, ui) {
             var url = ui.item.id;
             if(url != '#') {
                 location.href = '/admin/users/' + url+ '/edit';
             }
         },
  
         html: true, 
         open: function(event, ui) {
             $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
         }   
      });
});
```

```html
<input name="keyword" id="keyword" class="form-control txt-auto"/>
```

my function

```
public function search(Request $request) {
        $keyword = $request->input('keyword');
        $results = array();
        $user = User::where('username', 'LIKE','%'.$keyword.'%')->get();

        foreach ($user as $query)
        {
        $results[] = [ 'id' => $query->id, 'value' => $query->username ];
    }
    return Response::json($results);
    }

Route::get( '/search' , 'ShopController@search' );
```

[image: console response]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know i'm late to the party but I had this exact issue.

The z-index needs to be added while loading of your html:

What I did was I added this to one of my css files:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    z-index:2147483647;
}
```

After that, the autocomplete started working.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used autocomplete in a while, but I see two problems in your code. First, according to the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

> The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

Yet, you are using:

```
$keyword = $request->input('keyword');
```

instead of

```
$term = $request->input('term');
```

Second, maybe you need an ajax call inside the source option for something in particular, but you can simply do:

```
$('#keyword').autocomplete({
    source: "/search",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // ... do something here. Try logging the output
        console.log(ui.item);
    }
});
```